# SharePoint List Nested IF statatments

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, error, calculated-column-formula

I'm trying to write a code that checks the status of a column and if it's blank it then checks a different column and so on until it returns data. This is my syntax so far but it comes back as invalid:

```
=IF([Signed in DocuSign]= "Done", "Completed", "Budget Approved by Owner"), IF([Budget Approved by Owner]="Done", "Submitting to DocuSign", "Budget Sent to Owner"), IF([Send Budget to Owner]= "Done",  "Owner Reviewing Budget", "Sending to Owner"), IF([Internal Approval]= "Done", "Sending to Owner", "Approving Internally"), IF([Review Comments Cleared]= "Done",  "Budgets being Approved Internally", "Reviewing Updated Budget"), IF([Review Comments Addressed]= "Done", " Reviewing Updated Budgets", "Updating Budgets"), IF([Budget Reviewed]="Done", "Comments Being Addressed", "Reviewing Budget"), IF([Variance Comments Completed]= "Done", "Reports Being Reviewed", "REM Entering Variances"), IF([Reports Saved in SP]= "Done", "REM Entering Variances", "Saving Reports in SP"), IF([All Updates in rBudget]= "Done", "Saving Reports in SP", "Entering LA CapEx in rBudget"), IF([LA & CaPex Saved to SP]= "Done",  "Entering LA CapEx in rBudget", "Not Yet Started")
```

[image: My Current Columns]

Comment: Can you explain your requirements/conditions in detail? Do you want to show all the results (based on all columns) in single calculated column? Or do you need it conditionally like show result only based on single column (based on the latest stage in the process)?